# django Geonode python manage.py updatelayers fails

Tags: django

I've setup geonode and geoserver successfully and access the site using these installation instructions:

http://docs.geonode.org/en/master/tutorials/install_and_admin/geonode_install/index.html

However when I attempt to import the layers ive creater geoserver using the command python manage.py updatelayers I get the below error. I do not see anything obvious that would cause this, what are some possible solutions.

```
  File "manage.py", line 28, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/vol1/geonode/geonode/geonode/geoserver/management/commands/updatelayers.py", line 108, in handle
    remove_deleted=remove_deleted)
  File "/vol1/geonode/geonode/geonode/geoserver/helpers.py", line 458, in gs_slurp
    "bbox_y1": Decimal(resource.latlon_bbox[3])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 154, in get_or_create
    return self.get_queryset().get_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/modeltranslation/manager.py", line 341, in get_or_create
    return super(MultilingualQuerySet, self).get_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 383, in get_or_create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/polymorphic/polymorphic_model.py", line 90, in save
    return super(PolymorphicModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 545, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 582, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 185, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/vol1/geonode/geonode/geonode/geoserver/signals.py", line 470, in geoserver_post_save
    set_styles(instance, gs_catalog)
  File "/vol1/geonode/geonode/geonode/geoserver/helpers.py", line 776, in set_styles
    default_style = gs_layer.default_style
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geoserver/layer.py", line 103, in _get_default_style
    return self._resolve_style(element) if element is not None else None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geoserver/layer.py", line 111, in _resolve_style
    return self.catalog.get_style_by_url(style_workspace_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geoserver/catalog.py", line 798, in get_style_by_url
    dom = self.get_xml(style_workspace_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geoserver/catalog.py", line 211, in get_xml
    response, content = self.http.request(rest_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1570, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1317, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1290, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1060, in connect
    raise socket.error, msg
```

My apache log is :

```
[Fri Jun 23 13:28:18.967752 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 43112:tid 140088961779584] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Jun 23 08:28:19.085575 2017] [:error] [pid 43115:tid 140088961779584] Exception TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in <bound method LGEOS330.__del__ of <shapely.geos.LGEOS330 object at 0x7f68d5e77f58>> ignored
[Fri Jun 23 08:28:19.086615 2017] [:error] [pid 43117:tid 140088961779584] Exception TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in <bound method LGEOS330.__del__ of <shapely.geos.LGEOS330 object at 0x7f68d5df5050>> ignored
[Fri Jun 23 13:28:20.031722 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 56385:tid 140091668883328] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jun 23 13:28:20.031814 2017] [core:notice] [pid 56385:tid 140091668883328] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Jun 23 13:50:13.559525 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 56385:tid 140091668883328] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Jun 23 13:50:14.618523 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 56895:tid 140407831709568] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jun 23 13:50:14.618589 2017] [core:notice] [pid 56895:tid 140407831709568] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: But what is the actual error message. From the looks of it, it cannot connect to a remote service.

Comment: Could you please expand on your question? these are the only errors I have.

Comment: There should be a line before the traceback explaining the reason. Either way, this fails: `response, content = self.http.request(rest_url)`. So it cannot connect to whatever `rest_url` is.

Comment: @melvyn that got me pointed in the correct direction if you move it to an answer Ill mark it correct

Comment: FWIW. To explain ``"'NoneType' object is not callable"``, that is because the application must have background threads to run tasks. Those threads were still active when the process was being shutdown and the Python interpreter destroyed. Not really anything you can do to avoid it and since the process was being shutdown, usually not an issue. This is unrelated to the real problem you were having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the trace it looks like a connection to `rest_url` fails. Once you figure out what rest_url is and what it's supposed to be, you can solve your problem.